# SKEmitterNode for starfield... sprites are not opaque

Tags: macos, skspritenode, skemitternode

I'm working on a SpriteKit game in Swift that has a SKEmitterNode as a background rendering a star field.

I'm trying to make a few of my SKSpriteNodes (but not all) opaque to the background SKEmitterNode but I can't figure out how to do it. Setting the alpha value to 1.0 doesn't help; zPosition to +1 (and -1 on the SKEmitterNode) doesn't help. What am I missing?